# Single Sign-On for Web Applications (ASP.NET MVC) together with LDAP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap, single-sign-on

Our customer is using LDAP and 3 web application. The problem is the user is constantly forced to log on to each different web application.

He shall be able to use Windows authentication / LDAP together with single sign-on in order to be able to use all 3 Web apps without redirect to each login page.

So far, I have found this solution:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx

- in this case "This Web site verifies (Step 2) the user against their Windows credentials (through Active Directory)." I don't understand how to check users password.
  In this example is used only userid. Does it mean, that I'm only able to get users ID and check if a user with the same ID exists in LDAP ?

I would like to know, if there's an another and better way how to implement described functionality.
Please help